# PhpStorm didn't display any information of Xdebug

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I am new at Xdebug and trying to configure Xdebug with PhpStorm. The problem is, i can't get any information in phpstorm debug console even i hit a breakpoint. You can see the below picture phpstorm console when i hit a breakpoint

[image: When i run debug phpstorm didn't display anything]

**Here is my configurations**

1.Xdebug.ini Configurations

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.161
```

2.Xdebug Verification
[image]

3.1.PHPStorm Setting
[image]

3.2
[image]

3.3
[image]

Comment: PhpStorm version?

Comment: PhpStorm version 2018.1.4

Comment: You need PhpStorm 2018.3 or newer if you want to work with Xdebug 2.7.x. Either upgrade PhpStorm to latest stable version (2019.2) or downgrade Xdebug to 2.6 (it supports your PHP 7.2)

Comment: It worked now. Thanks LazyOne!!